# Where to find a full list of Eclipse4 Annotations?

Tags: annotations, eclipse-rcp

In hte following tutorial there are many, lifecycle and behavioural annotations:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#programmingmodel

- @PostConstruct
- @PreDestroy
- @Focus
- @Persist
- @PersistState
- @Execute
- @CanExecute
- @GroupUpdates
- @EventTopic

**QUESTIONS:**

Where can I find a full list of them? Is the there an official documentation?

I supose, that those annotations are from different frameworks (OSGI, Spring, etc.) 
Which annotations do come from which framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation on the specific annotations is pretty sparse at the moment, so there isn't a single place that you can go.

`@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` comes from JSR-250.

`@Inject` and `@Named` come from JSR-330

`@Persist`, `@PersistState`, and `@Focus` are annotations specific to the Eclipse4 UI rendering lifecycle.

`@Execute`, `@CanExecute`, `@Optional`, and `@GroupUpdates` are part of the Eclipse4 core DI story, to help with runtime notification of changes to DIed values or with method invocation in a DI context.

`@EventTopic` and `@Preference` are Eclipse4 DI extensions that can inject values from other provides and allow for notification of changes.

`@PostContextCreate`, `@PreSave`, `@ProcessAdditions`, and `@ProcessRemovals` are methods called as part of the Workbench Application lifecycle on the lifecycle manager.